# Unity UI Canvas selectable buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to add a C# script to my UI Canvas with OnSelect function, but I would like to select which buttons should be affected if I select them. So if I have like 5 buttons under Canvas and I only want to make 2 of them selectable how should I go about it? Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) , take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, input, obtained and expected output.

Comment: Welcome new user.  This is a completely fine, clear and good question.  **Simple** questions are perfectly welcome on SO.  So long as they are not dupes, or badly-written.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for asking a very newbie question. I'll pay more attention to creating questions in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's very easy.

1. In the Editor look in the Inspector,

[image]

you're looking for the "interactable" toggle.

Try "Play" your app in the Editor. When the buttons are visible, try toggling that in the Inspector!

2. In code, it's easy:

.

```
yourButton.interactable = false;
```

or "true".  It sounds like you would have five simple Inspector variables for each of your buttons.

```
public Button b1;
public Button b2;
```

and so on.

So just `b1.interactable = false;` and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! You explained it very well! I feel a bit ashamed to be honest that it was this easy.

Comment: It's not easy!  every single new Unity user struggles to find where the hell that setting is, since it is named weirdly.

Comment: It might be a dumb question again, but if I make the button not interactable it doesn't recognize the clicks either or any other functions it has so it loses it's purpose. Is there a method which allows the button it's functions but doesn't get recognized in the EventHandler if I hover over it? So I have a script on the Canvas, but I don't want the OnPointerEnter/Exit function to be called on a specific button which is a child of the Canvas itself. I hope it's understandable what I'm trying to say.

Comment: sure, hover still works.  try it.  alternately, *in the function* you call just do nothing.